# Fast algorithm to compute chi-square

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix, algorithms, matrix-factorization

I would like to evaluate the chi-square of the form $\chi^2=v^{T}C^{-1}v$ where $v$ is a column vector and $C$ is a covariance matrix. Both $v$ and $C$ are known and $C$ is a $740\times740$ matrix. All quantities involved are real valued.

The straightforward fastest way I know is to compute the solution to the equation $Cx=v$ (which does not involve computing $C^{-1}$ explicitly) and then compute chi-square. Is there any algorithm that could speed up the computation of $\chi^2$?

Comment: Do you have to perform this computation for many vectors $v$ while $C$ remains constant?

Comment: @BrianBorchers No $C$ doesn't remain constant. It is of the form $C=(A_0+\alpha A_1-\beta A_2)C'(A_0+\alpha A_1-\beta A_2)^T$ where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are varied numbers. All matrices are constant. The $A_i$'s are 740*2220 and $C'$ is 2220*2220.

Comment: @BrianBorchers Also one of the papers I am referencing mentions using the Sherman-Morrison-Woodbury to compute the inverse but I couldn't figure out how it would help. Anyway all suggestions are welcome.

Comment: You could compute the Cholesky factorization of C and then update it in each iteration.  This would be somewhat faster than computing the Cholesky factorization in each iteration, but shouldn't be a huge improvement since the Ai's are relatively large compared to C.

Comment: Is $C$ sparse or dense?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth $C$ is dense (as is $C'$). The $A_i$'s however are sparse $(A_k)_{i,j}=\delta_{3i,j+k}$, $k=0,1,2$

Comment: Are you using a high performance linear algebra library for these computations (e.g. Intel's MKL?)  What language are you programming in?

Comment: @BrianBorchers No, I am using numpy. All the programming is in python. Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: Chances are that NumPy on your system is using a very slow version of the BLAS and LAPACK linear algebra routines (quite likely the reference implementations.)  You could use Intel's distribution of Python to get the advantage of MKL's fast BLAS/LAPACK- this could easily be 5 to 10 times (or even more) faster than your current version.

Comment: @BrianBorchers So I wasn't aware about MKL and BLAS and all these things. Turns out the NumPy on my system uses openblas and looks like MKL can potentially speed up the computation. Thank you.

Comment: MKL will probably be slightly faster than OpenBLAS, but I wouldn't expect a huge improvement.

Answer (score 1):

No, as far as I know there are no shortcuts to compute a quantity of the form $v^T C^{-1} v$ that are essentially faster than $C^{-1}v$. You may save a little $O(n^2)$ effort, but this won't help against the whole algorithm which is $O(n^3)$ in practice (for small-scale, dense matrices).

If $C$ is ill-conditioned and stability is a concern, then you should probably consider using a QR factorization of the data series that has been used to compute $C$, rather than constructing $C$ itself. This is slower by a factor 2, but more stable.

And, with a matrix of that size, usually stability is a bigger concern than speed.